# Detect Key Press in System

Tags: node.js, keypress

I am trying to detect a `keypress` event outside the console tab, I have allready tried `input-event` (for linux), `hotkeys-js` (for browser), and `iohook` (gives error). How can I do it?

Comment: You want to detect a keypress on what? NodeJs is run as backend or CLI, not sure to follow what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to detect a key press anywhere in the computer to run a piece of code, like a toggle

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I used `iohook`, but the version `0.6.6` since the new version crashed, and called the `start` method.

```js
iohook.on('keypress', (res) => {
    let key = String.fromCharCode(res.rawcode);
    console.log(key);
});

iohook.start();
```